# Matlab + Neural Networks + 2 CUDA GPU cards PC experiment doesn't behave as I expect

Tags: matlab, gpu, neural-network

I did two experiments involving Matlab, Neural Networks, and two very different PCs. The second one (the better), has two CUDA GPU cards, so I expected that it's speed be higher a lot but contradictory the time to finish the same task as the first PC is 8 times more. I would like to know where I did the mistake. I would like to know how I can take advantage of those 2 CUDA GPU cards, because if I can't then I waste the money I invested on that computer. How can I modify that second code to be faster?. The Matlab version I used is: R2013a. Below you have two codes that you can run like that because they use a Matlab built-in dataset: house_dataset.

Thank you very much for your help!

**Computer 1:**

Specifications:
Laptop PC. Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2430M CPU @ 2.40GHZ (4 Cores). RAM: 4GB
OS: Window 7

**Script: test_script_NO_gpu_cuda**

```
clear all;
countTests = 200;
performances = zeros(1, countTests);
[x, t] = house_dataset;

tStart = tic;
for i = 1 : countTests,
    net = fitnet(10);
    net.trainFcn = 'trainscg';
    net.trainParam.showWindow = false;
    net = train(net, x, t, 'useParallel', 'yes', 'useGPU', 'only');
    y = net(x);
    per = perform(net, t, y);
    performances(i) = per;
end
elapsedTime = toc(tStart);

display(sprintf('Average performance: %.1f', mean(performances)));
display(sprintf('Elapsed time: %.1f seconds', elapsedTime));
```

>> **test_script_NO_gpu_cuda**
Average performance: 17.4
Elapsed time: 47.8 seconds

**Computer 2:**

Specifications:
Desktop PC. Two GPU of the same type: NVIDIA Tesla™ M2050 (448 cuda cores each one). RAM: 22 GB
OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

**Script: test_script_YES_gpu_cuda**

```
clear all;
matlabpool open
countTests = 200;
performances = zeros(1, countTests);
[x, t] = house_dataset;

tStart = tic;
for i = 1 : countTests,
    net = fitnet(10);
    net.trainFcn = 'trainscg';
    net.trainParam.showWindow = false;
    net = train(net, x, t, 'useParallel', 'yes', 'useGPU', 'only');
    y = net(x);
    per = perform(net, t, y);
    performances(i) = per;
end
elapsedTime = toc(tStart);
matlabpool close

display(sprintf('Average performance: %.1f', mean(performances)));
display(sprintf('Elapsed time: %.1f seconds', elapsedTime));
```

>> **test_script_YES_gpu_cuda**
Starting matlabpool using the 'local' profile ... connected to 8 workers.
Sending a stop signal to all the workers ... stopped.
Average performance: 18.7
Elapsed time: 373.9 seconds

Comment: Have you tried running `train` with `showResources` set to `yes`? That should show you whether the training was actually taking advantage of the MATLAB workers and/or GPUs. See the last section of http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/nnet/ug/parallel-and-gpu-computing.html

Comment: I modified the train line on the second script to: "net = train(net, x, t, 'useParallel', 'yes', 'useGPU', 'only', 'showResources', 'yes');". Then I got, on each cycle, the following output:

Computing Resources:
Parallel Workers:
  Worker 1 on localhost, GPU device #1, Tesla M2050 |
  Worker 2 on localhost, GPU device #2, Tesla M2050 |
  Worker 3 on localhost, Unused |
  Worker 4 on localhost, Unused |
  Worker 5 on localhost, Unused |
  Worker 6 on localhost, Unused |
  Worker 7 on localhost, Unused |
  Worker 8 on localhost, Unused.

Computing Resources:
MEX2. The rest keep the same. Thanks

Comment: Before I forgot to say that I also modified the net line of the second script to: "y = net(x, 'showResources', 'yes');". I would like to say, after comparing those two scripts, something like: "ohhh, it is a big good change of speed (increased)", but the result is just the opposite (decreased) hehehe

Comment: Is your computer #2 actually an amazon instance (cg1.4xlarge) ?

Comment: Is the GPU elapsed time of `373.9s` averaged over a number of program launches or is it the result of a single program launch?

Comment: The elapsed time is from the "tic" call to the "toc" call, so it is the sum of the elapsed time of all the "train" calls. See the second code.

Comment: Could you try a simpler example to check whether you can achieve greater speeds with the second setup?